# Podcast ep on iphone 5s will not delete

Tags: itunes, podcasts, iphone

I've moved to the UK and just got a new 5s phone and restored it from my old settings on my US iphone 5. One glitch I've noticed seems to be w/ iTunes music or podcasts showing up on the phone in songs when I didn't move them to the phone. I had 3 on there I didn't want. 2 deleted fine, just like any of the individual songs can delete. 1 podcast ep will not. I hold my finger down on it and slide to the left and no red delete option will show, but it will on any other song. I go to the ep, click the red lines in the top right corner to get me to the individual song again and while other songs will delete that way as well, this again will not. The red delete rectangle won't show. I hook it up to my mac and verify no podcasts are synced. The category is greyed out. The artist is not checked under artists, the individual ep is not checked, it's not in a playlist I've synced nor is it in genre I've synced. This is a complete mystery how this is still on the phone at all. It plays no problem, but I want it deleted off the phone entirely. I've turned the damn thing off/on a few times. How do I remove this? What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the settings app on iOS. Check podcasts and be sure to disable sync there. At that point a local delete should work properly.